# Show for all $ f,g \in R(\mathbb{T}) $ that $ \langle f,g \rangle = \sum_{ n= -\infty }^\infty \hat{f}(n) \overline{\hat{g}(n) } $

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-analysis

**Exercise:** Show for all $ f,g \in R(\mathbb{T}) $ that $ \langle f,g \rangle = \sum_{ n= -\infty }^\infty \hat{f}(n) \overline{\hat{g}(n) } $

**Notes:**

- $ R(\mathbb{T}) $ means the set of functions that are continuous on the interval $ [0, 2\pi] $ and also Riemman Integrable in this interval.
- $ S_{N} f = \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \hat{f}(n) e_{n} $
- $ e_{n}(t) = e^{int} $

**Proof from teacher assistant's notes:** for all $ N \in \mathbb{N} $, $\left\langle S_{N} f, S_{N} g\right\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{n=-N}^{N} \hat{f}(n) e_{n}, \sum_{m=-N}^{N} \hat{g}(m) e_{m}\right\rangle=\sum_{m, n=-N}^{N} \hat{f}(n) \overline{\hat{g}(n)}\left\langle e_{n}, e_{m}\right\rangle=\sum_{n=-N}^{N} \hat{f}(n) \overline{\hat{g}(n)}$
In addition $, S_{N} f \stackrel{L_{2}}{\longrightarrow} f, S_{N} g \stackrel{L_{2}}{\longrightarrow} g$ , hence from the continuity of the inner product with respect to convergence in $ L_2 $ it occurs that
$\langle f, g\rangle=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left\langle S_{N} f, S_{N} g\right\rangle=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n) \overline{\hat{g}(n)}$

**Question:**  I didn't understand the line
**"** hence from the continuity of the inner product with respect to convergence in $ L_2 $ it occurs that
$\langle f, g\rangle=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left\langle S_{N} f, S_{N} g\right\rangle=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n) \overline{\hat{g}(n)}$ **"**

How do we know that  $ \langle f, g\rangle=\lim _{N \rightarrow \infty}\left\langle S_{N} f, S_{N} g\right\rangle $? I don't know if the fourier sums converge pointwise to $f,g $.
From $, S_{N} f \stackrel{L_{2}}{\longrightarrow} f, S_{N} g \stackrel{L_{2}}{\longrightarrow} g $ I know ( by definition ) that $ || S_N f - f ||_2 \longrightarrow f $, $ || S_N g - g ||_2 \longrightarrow g $ and that's about it, so I don't see how this fact helps me.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f_n \to f$ in $L^{2}$ and $g_n \to g$ in $L^{2}$ then $ |\langle f_n, g_n \rangle-\langle f, g \rangle|=|\langle f_n, g_n \rangle-\langle f, g_n \rangle +\langle f, g_n \rangle-\langle f, g \rangle|\leq \|f_n-f\|\|g_n\|+\|f\|\|g_n-g\| \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks! , now I understand, $ | \langle S_N f , S_N g \rangle - \langle f,g \rangle | \leq || S_N f - f || \cdot || S_N g || + || f || \cdot || S_N g - g ||  \longrightarrow 0$ hence $ \lim_{N \to \infty} \langle S_N f , S_N g \rangle = \langle f,g \rangle  $